# Is there a way to detect whether a command prompt is available in python/django?

Tags: python, django

I have some code that will some times be run from a command line (django management command) and sometimes not (django changelist action).  In this code, if a certain exception is raised, I can get some user input and keep going if the a command prompt (stdin) is available.  Otherwise, I need to just let the exception propagate or do something different.

e.g.

```
def copy_account_settings(old_acct_domain, new_acct_domain):
  try:
    new_account = Account.objects.get(domain = new_acct_domain)
  except Account.DoesNotExist:
    print ("Couldn't find an account matching %s." % new_acct_domain)
    if <command prompt is available>:
      print "Would you like to create the account? (y/n)"
      if raw_input().lower().strip()='y':
        # get some more input and create the account and move on
    else:
      raise
```

How would you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can check for a TTY?

```
import os
if os.isatty(0):
```

That should return true if the session is interactive and false if not.